Add EventGridSystemTopicEventSubscription with deadletter not working with powershell
I want to create an event subscription for a FunctionApp but can not find how to define the DeadletterEndpoint. My pipeline has Az module v12.5.0 installed.
The following code is working but how can I define the storage account container for deadletter?
$funcid = "/subscriptions/$funcSubID/resourceGroups/$func_rg/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$funcapp/functions/$func_name"
$func_evdo = New-AzEventGridAzureFunctionEventSubscriptionDestinationObject -ResourceId $funcid

New-AzEventGridSystemTopicEventSubscription -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
        -eventSubscriptionName $eventSubscriptionName `
        -systemTopicName $systemTopicName `
        -destination $func_evdo

I mean the setting that I can configure in Azure portal here


Are you saying about dead letter queue?

No, I mean a dead letter container. I added a screenshot from Azure portal

You can use this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventgrid/controlplane/event-subscriptions/create-or-update?view=rest-eventgrid-controlplane-2022-06-15&tabs=HTTP#storageblobdeadletterdestination rest api and call it from powershell

Yes, with that one cannot create dead letter container name, rather use below api which allows to set dead lettering endpoint and I followed Microsoft-Document:
https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions/{eventSubscriptionName}?api-version=2022-06-15

Here scope is
'/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/{topicName}'
Api is working(Testing):
$testrithuri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/13fritth616/resourceGroups/rithwik/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/rithwik/eventSubscriptions/gggg?api-version=2022-06-15"
$beee = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://management.azure.com").Token
$ri_out = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $testrithuri -Method GET -Headers @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $beee"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}
$ri_out


I have tested the api for get, it is giving correct results, you can use the above api (PUT call) to create an event grid subscription with your desired features and details.

Yes, this is clear, thanks, I would assume Azure portal is also using the low level REST Api, all features must be implemented there. I solved it now by using Azure CLI.
My question here was specifically about the Az.Module and I think the parameter was there in older versions but then they forgot to implement it.

Yes, you are right, it might be in older versions.

@Frederic Good to accept the solution if it has solved the problem. This is for the benefit of the SO Community, refer SO Link
